# Диспетчер задач WINDOWS 7 - PHYSICAL MEMORY

Tags: windows, ram

Вопрос очень кажется глупым, но серьёзно не могу понять как смотреть мегабайты оперативной памяти по занявшим их процессам в WINDOWS 7?
В диспетчере задач и в мониторинге ресурсов и в сторонней программе resourcehacker есть колонки Private Working Set, Working Set, Commit size и т.д. Я просуммировал значения из каждой этих колонок и близко не получил 99% занятого памяти отображаемой в диспетчере задач как общий процент занятой памяти.

Comment: Дело в том, что одни и те же мегабайты оперативной памяти могут одновременно использоваться многими процессами. Обычно так происходит с часто открываемыми файлами и при IPC.

Comment: @VTT тогда чтобы при суммировании процентов получился общий процент диспетчера задач, посмотреть какой процесс использует память в процентах не возможно? Есть ли какие то программы? Нашел RAMMap но там тоже невидно.

Comment: В общем случае да. Как ни суммируй - выйдет больше или меньше общего процента. Кроме того, общий процент не учитывает кэши. А с кэшами потребление памяти обычно болтается на отметке 90% независимо от потребления памяти запущенными приложениями, то бишь совсем "не занятой" памяти очень мало.